# React. Fetch и useEffect. Рендер компонента несколько раз

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

```
export const API = (url, exportedData, isLoading) => {
    fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                return response.json().then((data) => {
                    let errorMess = "Auth failed";
                    if (data && data.errors) {
                        errorMess = data.errors;
                    }
                    console.log(errorMess);
                    throw new Error(errorMess);
                });
            }
        })
        .then((data) => {
            exportedData(data.payload);
            isLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};


import { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { API } from "../inc/helpers";
import Loading from "../components/Loading";

const Profile = () => {
    console.log("render Profile"); //срабатывает 3 раза

    const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState({});
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    const getData = (data) => setFetchedData({ ...data });

    useEffect(() => {
        API(
            "LINK/profile",
            getData,
            setIsLoading
        );
        console.log("useEffect Profile"); //срабатывает 2 раза
    }, [isLoading]);
```

Что я делаю не так, что он рендерит несколько раз одно и тоже?

Comment: Прочитайте про особенность `StrictMode` в реакте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Постараюсь это объяснить в два этапа, во втором со снипетом, предпочтительнее создавать именно снипеты, тем более сайт это позволяет.

*Я провел небольшой рефакторинг, который сохранил проблему но, на мой взгляд, писать лучше так, будет легче найти баги.*

Первое, что видится, это то что Вы дергаете `setState` из другого места (не из Компонента), это не очень здорово может порождать проблемы в некоторых случаях. Что касается `catch`, то он должен обрабатыватся тоже в Компоненте, иначе вы не получите return в некоторых случаях —  лучше все вернуть в `useEffect` и далее с этим работать. `catch` должен быть там где вы будете его как-то обрабатывать, например Вы можете захотеть отображать в компоненте, что загрузка не удалась. А `console.log` тоже не очень здорово писать вне методов Компонента (т.е. она отражает не то что Вы хотите, первый `рендер` он обязателен после монтирования, а далее Вы 2 раза обновляете стейт*, обновляя данные, и обновляя статус загрузки, поэтому всего их 3).

```
const API = (url) => {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  }).then((response) => response.json()) // это можно оставить тут
};

const Profile = () => {
    console.log("render Profile", Date.now()); //срабатывает 3 раза
    const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
          if (!isLoading){
            API("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos11/1")
              .then(data => {
                  setFetchedData(data);
                  setIsLoading(true) // <-- вызывает дополниельный рендер
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(`Что-то пошло не так: ${err}`);
              });
            console.log("useEffect Profile: fetching"); //срабатывает 1 раз
          } else {
            console.log("useEffect Profile"); //срабатывает 1 раз
          }
      })();
    }, [isLoading]);

    return <pre>Какая-то верстка {
      isLoading 
        ? JSON.stringify(fetchedData, null, 2)
        : 'Loading...'
    }</pre>
}
```

По итогу у нас такая картина:

- render Profile (**монтирование** и первый рендер )
- useEffect Profile: (причина: `isLoading==false`, загрузка данных)
- render Profile (причина: *обновление state `fetchedData`)
- render Profile (причина: *обновление state `isLoading==true`)
- useEffect (причина: обновление зависимости `isLoading==true`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта картинка жизненного цикла показывает когда происходит рендер — после монтирования или обновления состояния (state) или свойств (props).

**Способ избежать дополнительного рендера**

Сохранить удобство написания кода, можно используя хук `useReducer`:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  window.useState = React.useState;
  window.useEffect = React.useEffect
  window.useReducer = React.useReducer 

  const API = (url) => {
    return fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
    })
  };

  function reducer(state, action) {
    if (action.type =='load_data'){
      return {
        fetchedData: action.data,
        isLoading: true
      }
    }
  }

  const Profile = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
      reducer,
      { isLoading: false, fetchedData: null }
    );
    console.log("render Profile"); //срабатывает 2 раза
    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        if (!state.isLoading){
          API("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                dispatch({ type: 'load_data', data })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
            });
          console.log("useEffect Profile: fetching"); //срабатывает 1 раза
        } else {
          console.log("useEffect Profile"); //срабатывает 1 раза
        }
      })()  
    }, [state]);

    return <pre>Какая-то верстка {
      state.isLoading 
        ? JSON.stringify(state.fetchedData, null, 2)
        : 'Loading...'
    }</pre>
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode><Profile /></React.StrictMode>, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

В итоге наблюдаем следующую картину:

- render Profile (**монтирование** и первый рендер)
- useEffect Profile: fetching (причина: инициализация `state`, загрузка данных)
- render Profile (причина: обновление state )
- useEffect Profile (причина: обновление зависимости `state`)

*В итоге все становится на свои места, надеюсь мне удалось объяснить что проиходит, на счет рефакторинга не настаиваю, но по опыту скажу что есть практики которые изначально ведут к дальнейшим проблемам. Надеюсь, мой ответ окажется полезным.*

**P.S.** Что касается [строгого режима](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) или **React.StrictMode**, то его лучше использовать, он может помочь находить косяки, до того как они станут болью,но в текущем вопросе он не при чем, и но нужно учитывать:

> Проверки строгого режима работают только в режиме разработки; они не
> оказывают никакого эффекта в продакшен-сборке.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ, помогло понять и решить проблему.

Comment: Мой вызов делал 3 запроса АПИ. Я полностью скопировал код и получил 2 вызова. В итоге вычитал, что баг React и это в дев моде, в продакшне 1 вызов.